# What is the purpose of dot in batch file in if statement?

Tags: batch-file

What is the dot doing in following comparisons? (after %1 and ABCD, and in the line with %SOME_VAR%)

```
:begin
if not %1.==ABCD. goto no_abcd
some other code...
:no_abcd
code related to ABCD
....
if NOT %SOME_VAR%.==. goto begin
```

Comment: It is being used as a poor method of string checking, and has no specific purpose. I would suggest that you change it to, `If Not "%~1"=="ABCD" GoTo no_abcd`, or if you want to check that the first argument is `AbCd` or any other mixed case of those four characters in that order, `If /I Not "%~1"=="ABCD" GoTo no_abcd`. The second one similarly should read `If Defined SOME_VAR GoTo begin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot in that code is guaranteeing that you are comparing *something* to *something*.  Because comparing *nothing* to *something* in a batch file causes an error.

Consider this code:

```
if exist "c:\testfile.txt" set "FileExists=YES"
if %FileExists%==Yes echo We're all very happy
```

What happens if the file doesn't exist?  The variable `FileExists` will not be defined.  So in that scenario, the second if statement becomes:

```
if  ==Yes echo We're all very happy
```

And that will produce an error.  I usually see double quotes used instead of a dot like this:

```
if exist "c:\testfile.txt" set "FileExists=YES"
if "%FileExists%"=="Yes" echo We're all very happy
```

But basically anything to make sure both sides of a comparison are always *something*.  The code above could also work by simply making sure the variable is always defined:

```
set "FileExists=NO"
if exist "c:\testfile.txt" set "FileExists=YES"
if %FileExists%==Yes echo We're all very happy
```

Since the code now guarantees that the variable FileExists is always *something* (in this case NO or YES), we don't need double quotes or anything else.

The original code could have been:

```
:begin
if not "%~1"=="ABCD" goto no_abcd
some other code...
:no_abcd
code related to ABCD
....
if NOT "%SOME_VAR%"=="" goto begin
```